# Marshalling struct by reference in F#

Tags: f#, pinvoke, marshalling

I'm trying to rewrite the marshalling SysTime sample from the [Marshaling Classes, Structures, and Unions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/marshaling-classes-structures-and-unions#systime-sample) MSDN article from C# to F#.

My actual code now looks like this:

```
module LibWrap =
    open System.Runtime.InteropServices

    [<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
    type public SystemTime =
        struct
            val mutable public year:uint16
            val mutable public month:uint16
            val mutable public weekday:uint16
            val mutable public day:uint16
            val mutable public hour:uint16
            val mutable public minute:uint16
            val mutable public second:uint16
            val mutable public millisecond:uint16
        end 

    [<DllImport("Kernel32.dll")>]
    extern void GetSystemTime([<param:In>][<param: Out>]SystemTime st)


[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "F# SysTime Sample using Platform Invoke";
    let st = new LibWrap.SystemTime (month = 1us, day = 2us, year = 34us)
    try
        LibWrap.GetSystemTime st
    with 
        | ex -> printfn "Failed to GetSystemTime: %O" ex
    printfn "The Date is: %d/%d/%d" st.month st.day st.year
    0
```

It compiles and run with no exception but the output is not as expected. The values in the SystemTime structure are not overwritten.

**Output:**

```
F# SysTime Sample using Platform Invoke
The Date is: 1/2/34
```

If I run the code in the F# interactive console I got `System.AccessViolationException`. The C# version of the code works fine on my system. I tried to use `ref`/`byref` keywords but that did not help.

Any ideas what is wrong?
Any good source of information how to use P/Invoke and marshalling from F# correctly? I did not find much useful stuff.

Comment: Does adding the `CliMutable` attribute to your struct help? (Though I think it might have to be a record — I'm not all that familiar with this part of the language). If that doesn't work, check and see whether you can define your struct as a plain F# record with the `CliMutable` attribute. See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2012/07/19/more-about-f-3-0-language-features/ and https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/core.climutableattribute-class-%5Bfsharp%5D for more details.

Answer (score 3):

The Win32 [GetSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724390%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) function defines the struct parameter as a pointer.  That means your original code should work if you just change the way your external function is defined:

```
[<DllImport("Kernel32.dll")>]
extern void GetSystemTime(SystemTime& st)
```

Then you would tweak your main method to make `st` mutable and pass it like a pointer:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "F# SysTime Sample using Platform Invoke";
    let mutable st = LibWrap.SystemTime (month = 1us, day = 2us, year = 34us)
    try
        LibWrap.GetSystemTime &st
    with 
        | ex -> printfn "Failed to GetSystemTime: %O" ex
    printfn "The Date is: %d/%d/%d" st.month st.day st.year
    0
```

This prints:

```
F# SysTime Sample using Platform Invoke
The Date is: 7/6/2018
```

Answer (score 2):

As [rmunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314532/rmunn) suggested, the struct must be a plain F# record.

So this is the code that works for me:

```
module LibWrap =
    open System.Runtime.InteropServices

    [<CLIMutable>]
    [<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
    type SystemTime = {
        year:uint16
        month:uint16
        weekday:uint16
        day:uint16
        hour:uint16
        minute:uint16
        second:uint16
        millisecond:uint16
    }

    [<DllImport("Kernel32.dll")>]
    extern void GetSystemTime([<param:In>][<param: Out>]SystemTime st)

open LibWrap

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    printfn "F# SysTime Sample using Platform Invoke";
    let st = { year = 4us ; month = 1us ; day = 2us ; weekday = 0us ; hour = 0us ; minute = 0us ; second = 0us ; millisecond = 0us }
    try
        LibWrap.GetSystemTime st
    with 
        | ex -> printfn "Failed to GetSystemTime: %O" ex
    printfn "The Date is: %d/%d/%d" st.month st.day st.year
    0
```

The output is now as expected:

```
F# SysTime Sample using Platform Invoke
The Date is: 7/6/2018
```

Thanks for your hint, [rmunn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2314532/rmunn)